# Strange "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So playing around with node, thought I would write a straight forward news ticker to put on my very minimalistic node page, seemed like fun. The thing is, I keep on getting

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

But I can not for the life of me figure out where the error occurs. 
Have thrown is some additional debug comments, even removed parts of almost every file, but it all comes down to the same thing. If I start the application it gets to listening on port 3000 without problems. If I try to access it, i get the error message above.
Here is the app.js code

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , stylus = require('stylus')
  , nib = require('nib')
  , mongo = require('mongodb')
  , logger = require('express-logger')
  , bodyParser = require('body-parser')
  , methodOverride = require('express-method-override')
  , errorhandler = require('errorhandler')
  , monk = require('monk');






var app = express();

//Is this specifically for nib and stylus to work
function compile(str, path) {
    return stylus(str)
    .set('filename', path)
    .use(nib())
    }
// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
//app.use(express.favicon());
//app.use(express.logger('dev'));
//app.use(express.bodyParser());
//app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(stylus.middleware(
   { src: __dirname + '/public'
       , compile: compile
   }
));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//development only
//if ('development' === app.get('env')) {
//app.use(express.errorHandler());
//}

//Lets do some stuff to get info from the database

var db = monk('localhost:27017/meetallnews');
var router = express.Router();
//Make our db accessible to our router
app.use(function(req,res,next){
 req.db = db;
 next();
});
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Also, the routes/index.js

```
console.log('Called index.routes');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
exports.index = function(req, res){
    console.log('render page');
  res.render('index', { title: 'Meet All' });
};

//This is to read from the database
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Called database');
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('sitenews');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('newslist', {
            "newslist" : docs
        });
    });
});
```

Any suggestions welcome, even where to start looking. I removed the whole route.get section above, and still got the same (or an identical) error. Tried to remove stuff from the jade file, to the extent where there was only the header line left, still the same error message. And always after the server have reached end of app.js (have said Server on port 3000)

Comment: 1. Which version of express are you using? You use routers, which are express4 feature, but at the same time you have `app.use(app.router)` which is deprecated in this version.
2. Requesting which url causes the error
3. Is there any stack trace with the error?
4. Can you provide the source of the smallest version of the app (without all the stuff that you say that you had removed) which still gives you the error?

Comment: the stack trace is going to be huge, but 5) have you tried replacing your res.render(...) with just a plain `res.json({})` so that it doesn't matter what happens before it, and then commenting off all the code before it, uncommenting them one by one until you hit the infinite recursion? because then you'll know *what* is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much lukaszfiszer and Mr Pomax.

Turns out that the error message was a bit misleading, making me think it was some kind of eternal loop or some strange stuff from the database.

It was because I am a horrible thief and stole some code from somewhere for the routes, and missing to remove the line `app.use(app.router);` when also having `routes = require('./routes')`

Once that was removed I got a brand new error that I understand where it comes from and what it is (and not really related to this issue, only proves that untested coded must be tested.